# Dynamically populating JQuery DataTable

Tags: jquery-ui, jsp, jquery, jquery-plugins

I need to modify JQuery datatable in my JSP, where i have no static data for column creation.
Number of columns along with column names and data to be populated have to come from server.
How to code such JQuery DataTable.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create a dynamic array for both column and data value
$.post('ajax1', serilize, function(data) {
var list = data.list; 
    $.each(list[0], function(key, value) {   
       aaColumnvalue.push({"sTitle": value.columns_name},..}); 
    $.each(list[1], function(key, value) {   
       aaDatavalue.push([value.id,value.name,...]);
     }); 
)); enter code here
Here list[0] is dynamic column name and aaColumnvalue value array then pass these array value to datatable 
var table = $('#exampletable').dataTable({  
    "sScrollY": "200px",
    "sScrollX": "50%",
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "aaData": aaDatavalue,
    "aoColumns": aaColumnvalue
});
```